# Publishing a web application fails in VS2012 - access denied error

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday, my computer crashed. I reinstalled VS2012 and SQL server 2008 r2. Today, I tried to publish one of my applications, but I kept getting the following error. This happens only after reinstall the system.

```
Error   1   Copying file Uploads\Arts\large\img1.png to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Uploads\Arts\large\img1.png failed. Access to the path 'Uploads\Arts\large\img1.png' is denied.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried completely deleting the obj and bin directories?

Comment: @PreetSangha just tried that, not working.

Comment: anything in the  windows logs?

Comment: The only thing in such a state I can think of then is to repair first the visual studio and then if that fails, repair windows. Sorry

Comment: @PreetSangha both windows 7 and vs2012 just got reinstalled.